# Displaying list using panelgrid or anything except datatable

Tags: jquery, jsf

I want to display a list of property values using a panelgrid/panelgroup or anything that you can suggest me other than datatable because datatable needs column etc to display a list which i dont want to do in this case. 
My output should be like below example that has multiple discussions:

---

Employee name:              Designation:

Performance review:          Areas of interest:

Improvements:

---

Employee name:              Designation:

Performance review:         Areas of interest:

Improvements:

---

Comment: What's wrong with using an `ul` element?

Comment: If i use ul and li then the output goes down by down but instead i want to display like above

Comment: Have you tried using ui:repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ui:repeat>` for looping purposes, as it provides for a *markupless* iteration over its `value` elements. Inside the iteration you are free to create *any markup you want*. This basically means that using some CSS you could achieve the layout you want by using nested `<div>`s, or by using table-generating tags, like `<h:panelGrid>`, or by any other means.

Two examples. The first one, tableless:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.employees}" var="employee">
    <div class="employee-block">
        <div class="employee-line>
            #{msg.title}<h:inputText value=#{employee.title} ... />
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

The second one, using tables:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.employees}" var="employee">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
        #{msg.title}<h:inputText value=#{employee.title} ... />
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved using ui:repeat. Well it also worked using datatable with just column attribute inside it.

```
<panelGrid>
  <datatable value="#{list}" var="lst">
    <h:column>
      <panelGrid>
         <h:outputText value="#{lst.name}"/>
       </panelGrid>
    </h:column>
  </dataTable>
</panelGrid>
```

or

```
<panelGrid>
  <ui:repeat value="#{list}" var="lst">
      <panelGrid>
         <h:outputText value="#{lst.name}"/>
       </panelGrid>
  </ui:repeat>
</panelGrid>
```